# Div and span with the same height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to have my span with number "30" with the same height of the vertical line of the div that contains it.

```
#divDay {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 44px;
border-right: 2px solid #000;
margin-bottom: 6px;
margin-top: 10px;
height: 100%
}

#divDate {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 18px;
margin-bottom: 6px;
margin-top: 10px;

}

#divHeader{
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}


<div class="row">
    <div id="divHeader" class="col-xs-12">
        <div id="divDay" class="col-xs-2">
            <span>30</span>
        </div>
        <div id="divDate" class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="row">
                <span style="margin-left: 8px">Monday</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <span style="margin-left: 8px">April 2016</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                   
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h1m80Lv8/

Big thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you need to increase the font-size of "#divDay"

Comment: add `display: block; line-height: 51px;` to your span. Im not a html/css hacker but this suits your needs if I understand question good enough. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ttufcuk/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
#divDay {
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 100% 
}

#divDate {
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#divDay span { position:absolute;font-size: 72px;margin-top:-15px;}
#divHeader{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div id="divHeader" class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="divDay" class="col-xs-2">
      <span>30</span>
    </div>
    <div id="divDate" class="col-xs-10">
      <div class="row">
        <span style="margin-left: 8px">Monday</span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span style="margin-left: 8px">April 2016</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>                   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to give the span "display: block;"

```
#divDay>span {
    display: block;
}
```

[Check Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5ftLr06t/)

Answer (score 0):

More options:

```
<span style="padding: 6px;">30</span>
```

Or:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;">30</span>
```